# Select all descendant elements from a "li" element, except nested "li" element

Tags: html, xpath

I've got the following list:

```
<ul> 
      <li>Two potential pathophysiologic conditions lead to the clinical findings of HF, namely systolic and/or diastolic heart dysfunction. 
          <ul> 
               <li>Systolic dysfunction: an&#xa0;<i>inotropic</i>&#xa0;abnormality, due to myocardial infarction (MI) or dilated or ischemic cardiomyopathy (CM), resulting in diminished systolic emptying (ejection fraction &lt;45%).</li> 
               <li>Diastolic dysfunction: a&#xa0;<i>compliance</i>&#xa0;abnormality, due to hypertensive CM, in which ventricular relaxation is impaired (ejection fraction &gt;45%), resulting in decreased filling.</li> 
               <li>In an attempt to adopt a more pragmatic classification system, one that has been accepted by both the European and American HF guidelines, the terms HF with reduced, midrange, or preserved LVEF (HFrEF, HFmrEF, and HFpEF, respectively) have been adopted recently.</li> 
          </ul> </li> </ul>
```

I want to select text() from each "li" element, including all descendants (the text from the current "li" element, descendant "i",descendant "span", etc), except for descendant::li. I wanted to try something like this:

```
descendant-or-self[not(descendant::li)]/text().
```

What I would like to get is:

- From the first li: *Two potential pathophysiologic conditions lead to the clinical findings of HF, namely systolic and/or diastolic heart dysfunction.*
- From the second li: *Systolic dysfunction: an inotropic abnormality, due to myocardial infarction (MI) or dilated or ischemic cardiomyopathy (CM), resulting in diminished systolic emptying (ejection fraction <45%).*
- From the third li:*Diastolic dysfunction: compliance abnormality, due to hypertensive CM, in which ventricular relaxation is impaired (ejection fraction >45%), resulting in decreased filling.* etc.

**UPDATE:**

I didn't want to have the following text from the first "li" element:

*Two potential pathophysiologic conditions lead to the clinical findings of HF, namely systolic and/or diastolic heart dysfunction.Systolic dysfunction: an inotropic abnormality, due to myocardial infarction (MI) or dilated or ischemic cardiomyopathy (CM), resulting in diminished systolic emptying (ejection fraction <45%).Diastolic dysfunction: compliance abnormality, due to hypertensive CM, in which ventricular relaxation is impaired (ejection fraction >45%), resulting in decreased filling.* etc.

With the descendant-or-self::*/text() xpath I am getting the text above.

**UPDATE2:**
Please imagine that the first "li" also has a descendant "i" or "span":

```
 <ul> 
          <li>Two potential <i>pathophysiologic</i> conditions <span>lead to the</span> clinical findings of HF, namely systolic and/or diastolic heart dysfunction. 
              <ul> 
                   <li>Systolic dysfunction: an&#xa0;<i>inotropic</i>&#xa0;abnormality, due to myocardial infarction (MI) or dilated or ischemic cardiomyopathy (CM), resulting in diminished systolic emptying (ejection fraction &lt;45%).</li> 
                   <li>Diastolic dysfunction: a&#xa0;<i>compliance</i>&#xa0;abnormality, due to hypertensive CM, in which ventricular relaxation is impaired (ejection fraction &gt;45%), resulting in decreased filling.</li> 
                   <li>In an attempt to adopt a more pragmatic classification system, one that has been accepted by both the European and American HF guidelines, the terms HF with reduced, midrange, or preserved LVEF (HFrEF, HFmrEF, and HFpEF, respectively) have been adopted recently.</li> 
              </ul> </li> </ul>
```

I also wanted to have "i" and "span" text to get with the xpath. And also text from the other two lists (Systolic, Diastolic, but separately, not as a part of the first list's text).

Something like this:

```
(text() | descendant::span/text() | descendant::i/text())/normalize-space()
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you add which <li> you need to exclude from above example

Comment: Thank you for your attention @pareshm. Please take a look at the text in "UPDATE" section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select all text nodes descendant from a main li but not descendant from nested li elements (as described in your topic title), you can use the following XPath :

```
//text()[ancestor::li][count(ancestor::ul)=1][normalize-space()]
```

Output from your sample data (1 node) :

```
Two potential pathophysiologic conditions lead to the clinical findings of HF, namely systolic and/or diastolic heart dysfunction
```

EDIT : Based on your `UPDATE 2` requirements, you could use :

```
//*[self::i or self::span]/text()|//text()[parent::li][normalize-space()]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and attention @E.West. Please take a look at the "UPDATE2" part of my question.

Comment: Post has been edited. But your expected output is still unclear to me. Sometimes you want the text under nested li, sometimes you don't want it. Please define your expect output properly if the above solution doesn't suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works :) Sorry for the confusion :)